# Where did OP background color go?

Tags: bug, status-norepro, design

It seems like the background color on the name of the original poster is gone from the site and Meta. Normally the OP's name card on posts and comments are shaded to differentiate them. This appears to be gone.

The CSS rule

```
.owner {
    background: #F6F6F6;
}
```

should be corrected to

```
.owner {
    background: #F1F5E6; /* Or whatever the color should be */
}
```

Comment: It's showing up fine for me today, both here and on the main site.

Comment: F6F6F6 appears to be the right color, I'm also not seeing an issue.

Comment: I have to agree that these boxes are barely visible, especially the "edited" and "answered" boxes. The `quote` boxes are either well-distinguishable from the background (http://meta.android.stackexchange.com/questions/950/i-think-the-quote-blocks-should-be-more-visible-on-this-site#comment1526_950) Can't they be given a very little green tint?

Answer (score 2):

I can't repro. are you saying that you can't see #f6f6f6 bgcolor?

Comment: I'm saying that the `#f6f6f6` is too light against `#fff` to see here. I'm not sure if it there was a change, but I thought the color was more visible before (though I had swapped graphics card after the last time I had used this site, and the colors look slightly different after that), but in the [mockup](http://i.stack.imgur.com/fFqXo.png) you used `#F2F2F2` which has better contrast.

Comment: @YiJiang Sounds like you might want to check your monitor calibration, you will have lost any custom settings in your graphics card and drivers change, and been set to whatever the new defaults are. It could also be possible that plug and play isn't correctly identifying your monitor settings through the new card. What do you see on these calibration images http://epaperpress.com/monitorcal/index.html or http://www.lagom.nl/lcd-test/ ? (from SU http://superuser.com/questions/191702/free-monitor-calibration-tool)